# Changing ASP.NET MVC app to use different database or data based on dropdown selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an app built in ASP.NET MVC for a company to keep their job records, staff records etc. This company has recently acquired another company and wants their data in the app too, but separate.

They want to be able to select what company they want to manage in the header of the app from a dropdown list.

When changed, all of the views update and only display data for the company selected.

Not really sure where to start and what the best way to achieve this is? Has anyone done similar and could make a recommendation? Maybe I can do something with routes and have the company name/ID in the URL and retrieve data based on that?

I thought about a separate database or subdomain and just duplicate the app but they want to be able to do this from a single login so the existing app has to be modified to facilitate this.

Comment: If you're keen on a separate database then you could have the two connection strings in the config and dynamically choose which one to use based on user input, such as a drop-down selection.

Comment: you can use cookies that include company list and current company. when the user changed selcected company update current company. your requests should recieved firstly by a method that must called before the action method is invoked. in there you can set needs for configs by using cookies